# ASP.NET MVC : unobtrusive-ajax for dynamically added forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajaxform, unobtrusive-ajax

I'm loading an **Ajax Form** inside a popup. the popup content is written client side.

**unobtrusive-ajax** is not triggered by the form. and its events are not called.

This is because of loading the **Ajax Form** dynamically. and unobtrusive-ajax is **not binded** to it.

Is there any method for binding dynamically loaded ajax forms with **unobtrusive-ajax** ?

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset validation for validating dynamically loaded form. after loading form in popup window
reset validation:

```
var form = $('your form');
form.removeData('validator');
form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your answer is right. but my problem is not about validations. I already done this workaround. and validation is working.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. unobtrusive-ajax is working with dynamically added forms. and events are binded. Problem was about copying my markup inside popup and I had two items with same ID. jquery selectors was not working.

I removed my original markup (that I was copying inside popup). and everything is ok now.